# Share Oracle database pool along subsites on the same Applicacion Pool on IIS 7

Tags: oracle, iis

I'm having a problem with Oracle pools and IIS 7. I've written two webservices and deployed them as subsites on the same virtual folder both using the same applicacion pool. Both services use an Oracle pool (configured inside their Web.config using the same connection string) that stablish 10 as the minimun connections per pool.

As I understood it, both webservice should use the same database pool as they are running on the same Application pool, but I find that this is not the case.

I launched a request on the first webservice and (using v$session view) I see that 10 sessions are created (the correct minimun size of the pool). Nevertheless, when I launch a request to the other webservice, another 10 connections are created. So, it seems each webservice has its own database pool.

I tried to send more requests to the webservices and the connections do not grow (as expected).

How could I share the same Oracle database pool along all the subsites running on the same Applicacion Pool?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more like an iis problem.
But you could use a database resident connection pool for this. That can be shared across applications.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdbc/database-resident-connection-pooling.html#GUID-D4F9DBD7-7DC6-4233-B831-933809173E39

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is a IIS configuration problem. I'll try to push the DRCP solution, but I'm afraid it is beyond me (as I'm not the DBA). Any clue about where could I start searching to explore the IIS configuration lead? Thank you very much

Comment: Drcp is pretty simple. Any dba will be happy to help you since it generally is a good tool to keep the database safe and healthy.

Comment: Thank you. I'll see if someone can help about IIS configuration and mark answered

Comment: too bad I can not help you with the oracle configuration for DRCP. Any sensible dba would love to accept that above external connection pools, that frequency have problems and overload the database. Thanks foor acccepting.